# PHP loses newline when there is no more symbols at the end of a line

Tags: php

I run this PHP file from console and getting one line instead of three. Why PHP acts like that? Where does my newline symbol gone? It keeps newline only if PHP was not last statement on the line. This is kind of weird and unobvious, isn't it? Is there any documentation entry on this behavior or this is a bug?

```
<?php ?>

foo = <?= 'foo' ?>
bar = <?= 'bar' ?>
baz = <?= 'baz' ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how PHP works. If the closing tag `?>` is immediately followed by a newline, that newline is stripped from the output (technically, it is considered to be part of the closing tag).

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php):

> The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

Note that this only applies to the *first* newline after the closing tag; if you add more, they will appear in the output normally.

Comment: Can you give link to the documentation?

Comment: Thanks... anyway, this is weird IMO.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I do have a feeling there was some other way in the early years of PHP - something like, if the closing tag was /?> it would add a newline... No?